# Is there a work around for position fixed when rotating device?

Tags: css, position, fixed

I have a DIV with the following properties:

```
#navigation
{
    position            : fixed;
    left                : 0%;
    top                 : 0%;

    display             : block;
    width               : 100%;
    height              : 44px;

    text-align          : center;

    background          : #171717;

    -webkit-transform   : translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

The webkit transform is needed to keep the bar in position when the user is scrolling.

However, when I am in portrait and scroll and then rotate the device to landscape. The bar is vanished. When I scroll in landscape the bar snaps back into it's proper position.

When I then rotate the device back to portrait the bar is half in screen untill I scroll again and it snaps back to it's proper position again.

I think this has to with redrawing the object, is there a way to force this on rotation?

**EDIT: THIS ONLY OCCURS WHEN YOU HAVE THE APPLICATION IN STANDALONE MODE (ADDED TO HOMESCREEN)**